# Check for Cycles in Adjacency Matrix?

Tags: java, algorithm, cycle, adjacency-matrix

One of my methods in Java passes in an adjacency matrix with

- **`1`** values in matrix indicating a connection, and
- **`0`** values indicating no connection.

My adjacency matrix represents an un-directed graph.

How can I check whether my adjacency matrix has any cycles or not?

Comment: Have a look at [Cycle Detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)#Cycle_detection).

Comment: Does anyone have any idea how to do this? Even pseduocode? I've done a lot of Google searching and eve here, but have found nothing.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25537032/58866

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two good solutions:

1. begin to traverse (bfs, dfs , ...) your graph if you visited a node twice there is cycle in your graph.
2. hence you have a adjacency matrix, then you could use algorithm that Imran mentioned in comment, you just need to compute A<sup>n</sup>, for n = 1 , .... and check if there is non zero diagonal entry or not, and I think your teacher wants this algorithm.

Just google `adjacency matrix properties` and you will find articles like [this](http://1stprinciples.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/some-interesting-properties-of-adjacency-matrices/).

Comment: So if the DFS traversal visits ANY element in the adjacency matrix twice, then there is a cycle?

Comment: @Vimzy if it visit ANY Node twice there is a cycle. but as I said it is better to use the second approach

Comment: I'm not quite understanding the second approach to be honest. How do I compute A^n and how would I be able to check if there is non zero diagonal entry or not?

Comment: @Vimzy A^1 is basic matrix! A^2 is A*A and ... and for checking diagonal entry, just check A[0][0], A[1][1] ,.... and see if there is a number bigger than zero in every step.