# Is there any efficient algorithm to find the length of the longest cycle in a undirected graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, cycle

I want to know that is there any efficient algorithm to find the length of the longest cycle in a graph?

The graph is an undirected graph.

The algorithm doesn't have to tell what vertex is in the cycle, just only the length.

Comment: The longest possible cycle in a graph would be a [Hamiltonian cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path). To quote the article: *"Determining whether such [...] cycles exist in graphs [...] is NP-complete."*

Comment: so there is no algorithm that works in polynomial time.

Comment: That would be my answer, but we'll see if someone says otherwise. OTOH, if there are constraints on the graph, those constraints could make the problem easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem of finding the longest cycle in a graph is **NP-hard**, because solving this problem allows to answer the question "**Is this graph hamiltonian ?**" (does it possess an hamiltonian cycle), which is itself a NP-complete problem.
So, indeed, no efficient algorithm can do that.
There are methods based on matrix multiplication to find a cycle of length `k` in a graph.
You can find explanations about finding cycles using matrix multiplication in [this quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436165/detecting-cycles-in-an-adjacency-matrix). But beware, the matrix multiplication methods allows to detect `walks` of a given length between 2 vertices, and the repetition of vertices is allowed in a walk.