# How to convert an iterative function that checks for cycles in an adjacency matrix, to a simpler, recursive function in C?

Tags: c, recursion, cs50

Having trouble grasping recursive thinking, and a lot of what I've seen on Stack overflow so far I don't understand.

I'm trying to detect a cycle in a directed graph, given a 2D array adjacency matrix where a value of true for graph[i][j] indicates an edge from i to j.

Have created a check_cycles function which checks for a path from j to i, given graph[i][j] and have hard coded the size of the graph to simplify the issue.

I am getting a return value of true as expected with this code, but as you can see, now I've hard coded a lot of for loops, and this would be impractical should the size or values passed to the function be changed.

How would I find a recursive solution to this? What would be the case in which the function should stop running?

Right now I'm using a library that allows for a bool return value on functions, but it could as well return void.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>


//hard coding the size of the graph
int size = 5;

//set up an adjecency matrix
bool graph[5][5];

//functions
bool check_cycles(int index1, int index2);

int main(void)
{

  //setting the graph values to false
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
      graph[i][j] = false;
    }
  }

  //hard coding a cycle into the graph
  graph[0][1] = true;
  graph[1][2] = true;
  graph[2][3] = true;
  graph[3][0] = true;

//check for cycles
  printf(check_cycles(2,3)? "Cycle detected\n" : "No cycles\n");

}



bool check_cycles(int index1, int index2)
{  
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  { 
    //check for adjacent edge
    if (graph[index2][i] == true)
    {
      //check if edge points to initial node
      if (graph[i][index1] == true)
      {
        return true;
      }
      else 
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
          if (graph[i][j] == true)
          {
            if (graph[j][index1] == true)
            {
              return true;
            }
            else  
            {
              for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
              {
                if (graph[j][k] == true)
                {
                  if (graph[k][index1] == true)
                  {
                    return true;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
return false;
}
```

Comment: For both the iterative and the recursive solution you should be passing the size of the graph as a parameter

Comment: Is the primary purpose of your function to search for cycles or to search for a path from one designated node to the other?  It seems to be the latter, in which case the choice of function name is terrible.

Comment: Either way, recursion is no silver bullet.  Each of the two problems affords iterative solutions whose structures are not specific to any particular problem size, and these are not necessarily any harder to conceive or understand than recursive ones.

Answer (score 0):

This idea of hardcoding may seem like a nice way to start, but as you've noticed, a fundamentally different strategy is going to be necessary to solve problems like this.

Cycle detection can be done naively running a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) starting from every node. Before beginning, create an empty set to keep track of visited nodes. When you visit a node, first look it up in the set. If it's already there, you've found a cycle; otherwise, mark it visited and search all of its adjacent neighbors. If you don't find any cycles for a node, mark it unvisited before exiting its call frame to avoid false positives if there are multiple paths to it.

You can do this iteratively using a stack and a loop. pop the stack to visit a node and push its neighbors onto the stack. The fundamental approach is the same in that you're using lookups on a visited set to detect cycles.

Once you have the basic implementation, you may wish to [optimize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436165/detecting-cycles-in-an-adjacency-matrix).

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool is_cyclic_(int curr, int n, bool **graph, bool **visited) {
    if ((*visited)[curr]) {
        return true;
    }

    (*visited)[curr] = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (graph[curr][i] && is_cyclic_(i, n, graph, visited)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    (*visited)[curr] = false;
    return false;
}

bool is_cyclic(int n, bool **graph) {
    bool *visited = calloc(n, sizeof(*visited));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {        
        if (is_cyclic_(i, n, graph, &visited)) {
            free(visited);
            return true;
        }
    }

    free(visited);
    return false;
}

int main() {
    int n = 5;
    bool graph[][5] = {
        {0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,1},
        {0,0,1,0,0},
        {1,0,0,0,0},
    };
    bool **pgraph = malloc(sizeof(*pgraph) * n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        pgraph[i] = malloc(sizeof(pgraph[i]) * n);

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            pgraph[i][j] = graph[i][j];
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", is_cyclic(n, pgraph));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        free(pgraph[i]);
    }

    free(pgraph);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! I figured this out eventually -- I was overcomplicating the problem. 
My cycle function is, in effect, searching for a path, from node a to b, given that the edge b to a is already set to true.

I was then able to use recursion as follows, size was a global variable --

```
bool check_path(int index2, int index1)
{
    if (index1 == index2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
            if (graph[index2][i] == true)
        {
            if (check_path(i, index1))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```